# Match document root node with a prefix

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I have a XML document which root node is `sv:node` and I am trying to define a template who match this root node.
When my root node has no prefix it usually works but in this case an exception is thrown.

```
<xsl:template name="/sv:node" />
```

I am using JAVA with the [Apache XALAN XSLT processor](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) which raises a `RuntimeException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Le préfixe doit se convertir en espace de noms : /sv
    at org.apache.xml.utils.QName.<init>(QName.java:450)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTAttributeDef.processQNAME(XSLTAttributeDef.java:937)
```

*I apologize about the localized message of the `RuntimeException`, basically it is complaining about the prefix with is not mapped to a namespace.*

So the question is, how can I match this root node?

Edit : Here is my `stylesheet` tag 
 Here is my stylesheet tag :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:zip="http://apache.org/cocoon/zip-archive/1.0"
            xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you really meant

```
<xsl:template match="/sv:node" />
```

(with `match` rather than `name`).  Using `<xsl:template name="...">` declares a *named template* which can be called by `<xsl:call-template>`, not a *matching template* for `<xsl:apply-templates>`, and the name of a named template must be a QName.  The exception is telling you that it's trying to treat the three characters "forward-slash, s, v" as the prefix part of the QName and finding that this prefix is not mapped to a URI.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake, I was using

```
<xsl:template name="/sv:node" />
```

instead of

```
<xsl:template match="/sv:node" />
```